# Avoid narrowing conversion for bitset template

Tags: c++

How can the following be written in a portable way to avoid narrowing conversions?

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

template <typename T>
auto int_to_bitset(T x)
{
    //return std::bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>{x}; // does not work, narrowing conversion to unsigned type
    //return std::bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>{static_cast<unsigned int>(x)}; // might not have the same size as T
    //return std::bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>{static_cast<unsigned T>(x)}; // What I would like to do, but does not work. I've never seen so many errors.
    return std::bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>(x); // works, but selects unsigned long long for the constructor's parameter on my system. Can this conversion be relied on?
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << int_to_bitset<short>( 1  ) << '\n';
    std::cout << int_to_bitset<short>(-1  ) << '\n';
    std::cout << int_to_bitset       ( 1  ) << '\n';
    std::cout << int_to_bitset       (-1  ) << '\n';
    std::cout << int_to_bitset       ( 1L ) << '\n';
    std::cout << int_to_bitset       (-1L ) << '\n';
    std::cout << int_to_bitset       ( 1LL) << '\n';
    std::cout << int_to_bitset       (-1LL) << '\n';
}
```

Produces:

```
0000000000000001
1111111111111111
00000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: how about `std::make_unsigned`? seems to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ada1221fa10574d3

Comment: @m.s. Works perfectly. Even on VS2015. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::make_unsigned`:

```
template <typename T>
auto int_to_bitset(T x)
{
    return std::bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT>{static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(x)};
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ada1221fa10574d3)